# How do I print a Groovy stack trace?

Tags: groovy

How do I print a Groovy stack trace? The Java method, Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() produces a huge stack trace, including a lot of the Groovy internals. I'm seeing a function called twice from a StreamingMarkupBuilder that looks like it should only be called once and I would like to see why Groovy thinks it should be calling it twice.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StackTraceUtils.sanitize(new Exception()).printStackTrace()
```

**Original answer:**

A Google search returns the [following information:](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/StackTraceUtils.html)

Apparently, there is a method in `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StackTraceUtils` called `printSanitizedStackTrace`.  There isn't much documentation for the method, though there is a method called `sanitize` which is described as

> remove all apparently groovy-internal
>   trace entries from the exception
>   instance This modifies the original
>   instance and returns it, it does not
>   clone

So I would try `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StackTraceUtils.printSanitizedStackTrace(Throwable t)` (it is static)
and see if that works for you.

Comment: Final solution: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StackTraceUtils.sanitize(new Exception()).printStackTrace(). For some reason printSanitizedStackTrace() doesn't work.

Comment: It could be that printSanitizedStackTrace() doesn't behave as you expect because you're expecting the output in System.out, while printSanitizedStackTrace() sends it to System.err. I tried adding a PrintWriter constructed from add System.out as the second parameter, after the Throwable object, but still didn't get anything like I was expecting in the output.

Comment: This works for me: ```org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StackTraceUtils.sanitize(new Exception(e)).printStackTrace()``` where ```e``` is the catch-ed Exception

Comment: The link in the answer is broken

Answer (score 6):

I found this questions when searching for `"spock print full stack trace"`.

My unit tests are written in Groovy, using the Spock testing framework and they're run in the context of a Gradle build.

The fix for me was as simple as adding `exceptionFormat = 'full'` to my Gradle test task specification:

```
test {
  testLogging {
    exceptionFormat = 'full'
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This really helped fixing my spock unit test cases

Answer (score 3):

I have designed this simple code for stack trace printing, based on artificial simulation of a NullPointerException.
This code produces the same output in both modes: from a Jenkinsfile (Pipeline) and from a normal .groovy script in a command line.

```
def getStackTrace() {
    try {
        null.class.toString() // simulate NPE
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        return e.getStackTrace()
    }
    return null
}

def printStackTrace() {
    def stackTraceStr = ""
    def callingFuncFound = false
    for (StackTraceElement ste : getStackTrace()) {
        if (callingFuncFound) {
            stackTraceStr += ste.toString() + '\n'
        }
        if (!callingFuncFound && ste.toString().startsWith(this.class.name + '.printStackTrace(')) {
            callingFuncFound = true
        }
    }
    println(stackTraceStr)
}
```

Some explanations:

1. The output is concatenated into a single string to avoid being mixed with "[Pipeline] echo" message prefix of Jenkins Pipeline's println()).
2. The number of "unnecessary" upper stack trace elements related to the NPE is different in Jenkinsfile and in a normal command line. This is why I calculate *callingFuncFound* and don't use just something like *e.getStackTrace()[2..-1]* to skip them.