# Gradle task does not show Java stacktrace

Tags: java, gradle

This is my task to execute the main-method of a class, defined in the build.gradle of a Java project:

```
task(runClass, type: JavaExec) {
    try {
        main = project.getProperty('c')
    }
    catch (Throwable t) {}
    if(project.hasProperty('myargs')){
        args(myargs.split(' '))
    }
    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
    jvmArgs("-ea")
}
```

Example:

```
gradle -q runClass -Pc=my.proj.MyClass -Pmyargs="arg1 arg2"
```

**Problem**: If execution fails because of an uncatched exception I don't get gradle to print the Java stacktrace - only regular outputs of my program and Gradle internals are printed:

```
2018-08-01 20:37:15.501 program output ...
...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':myproj:runClass'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':myproj:runClass'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:196)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:369)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultJavaExecAction.execute(DefaultJavaExecAction.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.exec(JavaExec.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:141)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:632)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:615)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
        ... 70 more
```

The Gradle failure tells that "build" has failed but the failure is caused by an exception in my program. Starting a flawless programm wouldn't cause this failure. Using --stacktrace gives the output above - but org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException does not show any internals of the Java stacktrace that could lead me to the point of failure. Using --debug or --info does not help either, but shows the command:

```
Executing task ':myproj:runClass' (up-to-date check took 0.0 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
Starting process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''. Working directory: ... Command: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx4g -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=DE -Duser.language=de -Duser.variant -ea -cp .../myproj/build/classes/test:.../myproj/build/resources/test:.../myproj/build/classes/main:.../myproj/build/resources/main:.../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.sourceforge.streamsupport/streamsupport/1.6.3/a06337a1bb1131f90e277a0d55dd6c0b94579b24/streamsupport-1.6.3.jar:.../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/20.0/89507701249388e1ed5ddcf8c41f4ce1be7831ef/guava-20.0.jar:.../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/de.ruedigermoeller/fst/2.56/6711f096910c4dfe388936b13def643d458a51e3/fst-2.56.jar:.../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/junit/junit/4.12/2973d150c0dc1fefe998f834810d68f278ea58ec/junit-4.12.jar:.../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.8.8/d478fb6de45a7c3d2cad07c8ad70c7f0a797a020/jackson-core-2.8.8.jar:.../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javassist/javassist/3.21.0-GA/598244f595db5c5fb713731eddbb1c91a58d959b/javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar:.../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.objenesis/objenesis/2.5.1/272bab9a4e5994757044d1fc43ce480c8cb907a4/objenesis-2.5.1.jar:.../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/42a25dc3219429f0e5d060061f71acb49bf010a0/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar ....example.MyClass
Successfully started process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''
```

... and the result:

```
Stopped 0 worker daemon(s).
Received result Failure[value=org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':myproj:runClass'.] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=43471, address=[982cf8c3-fcff-4115-8e8d-bca1df25cac4 port:57301, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, /127.0.0.1]], state=Idle, lastBusy=1533151971365, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=e89acbd5-ee61-49b2-b863-d205f0b4230d,javaHome=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home,daemonRegistryDir=.../.gradle/daemon,pid=43471,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-Xmx6656M,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=DE,-Duser.language=de,-Duser.variant]} (build should be done).
```

Putting the whole main body into try/catch blocks wont print anything with `t.printStackTrace();`, but with `System.out.println(Throwables.getStackTraceAsString(t));`, which is really strange.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a stacktrace because you never call it in your catch block. It should look something like

```
try{


}catch(Throwable t){

    t.printStackTrace();
    .....
}
```

though if you're looking for any possible exception, and not a throwable, I'd recommend

```
  (Exception t)
```

instead.

Edit:

While my answer here wasn't correct, it looks like this solution can actually be found here:

[How do I print a Groovy stack trace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259202/how-do-i-print-a-groovy-stack-trace)

Comment: As far as I know, this is not the place, where main is executed, but only where the class name is read. Anyway, I added your code, the result is (within Android Studio): `Error:(59, 0) No signature of method: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException.printStacktrace() is applicable for argument types: (org.gradle.internal.io.LinePerThreadBufferingOutputStream) values: [org.gradle.internal.io.LinePerThreadBufferingOutputStream@7f25c909]
Possible solutions: printStackTrace(), printStackTrace(java.io.PrintStream), printStackTrace(java.io.PrintWriter), getStackTrace()
...`

Comment: Using `System.out.println(t.getStackTrace()` or `t);` results in the same behavior: No internal stacktrace is printed.

Comment: I'm sorry, the problem has had a completely other cause: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51641805/using-consolehandler-with-system-out-suppresses-system-err