# Using ConsoleHandler with own PrintStream suppresses System.err

Tags: java, java.util.logging

I want the Java `ConsoleHandler` to use `System.out` instead of `err`, so I implemented my own handler that calls the `protected void setOutputStream(OutputStream)` of the parent `StreamHandler` class:

```
public class ConsoleHandler extends java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler {

    public ConsoleHandler() {

        setOutputStream(System.out); // or System.err
        setLevel(Level.ALL);
    }
}
```

I remove the default console logger from and add my own to the root logger:

```
Logger l = Logger.getLogger("");
for (Handler h : l.getHandlers())
    l.removeHandler(h);
l.addHandler(new ConsoleHandler());

System.out.println("OUT");
System.err.println("ERR");
```

**Problem:** "OUT" is always printed, but "ERR" never, independent of the output stream I set in my ConsoleHandler constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The stacktrace (printed to System.err) is not printed any more, without my changes it is printed as usual

This is because `setOutputStream` [closes the previously assigned `System.err` stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194165/how-do-i-change-java-logging-console-output-from-std-err-to-std-out/35919737).  This is a known issue filed under [JDK-4827381: Invoking ConsoleHandler.setOutputStream(...) closes System.err](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4827381).  What should have happened with that bug report is that the [StreamHandler.setOutputStream](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/logging/StreamHandler.java) should call `Handler.close` instead of `flushAndClose()`.

You need to wrap the existing `System.err` stream with a proxy that doesn't allow the stream to be closed. Or just extend `StreamHandler` and use the constructor that takes an OutputStream.

```
public class OutConsoleHandler extends StreamHandler {

   public OutConsoleHandler() {
        super(System.out, new SimpleFormatter());
        //TODO: Read level,filter,encoding from LogManager.
   }

    @Override
    public void publish(LogRecord record) {
        super.publish(record);
        super.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        super.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: This was my guess. How is it possible that `System.err.close()` does not throw an UnsupportedOperationException? This shouldn't be allowed in Java land.I accept your solution while pointing to the JDK ConsoleHandler implementation which is a bit more complex: https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/logging/ConsoleHandler.java

Comment: @Andi If you are using the `logging.properties` then you have to roll your own.  However, if you are using code and you control how things start up then you [use the existing console handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194165/how-do-i-change-java-logging-console-output-from-std-err-to-std-out/35919737#35919737).

Comment: How is it possible?  I guess because there are conceivable use-cases where you would really want System.err.close() to close the stream.